# C++ makefile with MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, makefile

I am trying to build C++ code under Linux. Its my first attempt (otherwise, I use only Windows). My code is using MySQL C API library, but I have problem building it. I got this output while trying to build MainProgram

```
g++ -lstdc++ -c  MainProgram.cpp `mysql_config -–libs` -O2 -o MainProgram.obj `mysql_config –-cflags`

   g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
   Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And then linking is not done, because MainProgram.obj is missing

My makefile is this:

```
CC = g++ CFLAGS = -lm -lstdc++  -Wall -O2  

MYSQLCFLAGS = `mysql_config –-cflags` 
MYSQLLIBS   = `mysql_config -–libs`

BIN = my_program


OBJ = BlockingSocket.obj FTPClient.obj FTPDataTypes.obj FTPFileStatus.obj FTPListParse.obj MyStringAnsi.obj MainProgram.obj 



.PHONY: sestav .PHONY: clean


#-----------------------------------------

clean:  rm -f *.obj


#----------------------------------------- 

sestav: ${BIN}


#-----------------------------------------

$(BIN): $(OBJ) $(OBJ)   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@


#-----------------------------------------

BlockingSocket.obj: ./FtpClient/BlockingSocket.cpp  $(CC) -c ./FtpClient/BlockingSocket.cpp -O2 -o BlockingSocket.obj

#-------

FTPClient.obj: ./FtpClient/FTPClient.cpp    
  $(CC) -c ./FtpClient/FTPClient.cpp -O2 -o FTPClient.obj

FTPDataTypes.obj: ./FtpClient/FTPDataTypes.cpp  
  $(CC) -c ./FtpClient/FTPDataTypes.cpp -O2 -o FTPDataTypes.obj

FTPFileStatus.obj: ./FtpClient/FTPFileStatus.cpp    
  $(CC) -c ./FtpClient/FTPFileStatus.cpp -O2 -o FTPFileStatus.obj    

FTPListParse.obj: ./FtpClient/FTPListParse.cpp  
  $(CC) -c ./FtpClient/FTPListParse.cpp -O2 -o FTPListParse.obj

MyStringAnsi.obj: MyStringAnsi.cpp  
  $(CC) -c MyStringAnsi.cpp -O2 -o MyStringAnsi.obj


MainProgram.obj: MainProgram.cpp   
  $(CC) -lstdc++ -c  MainProgram.cpp $(MYSQLLIBS) -O2 -o MainProgram.obj $(MYSQLCFLAGS)
```

Complete output when building from scratch:

```
g++ -c ./FtpClient/BlockingSocket.cpp -O2 -o BlockingSocket.obj
g++ -c ./FtpClient/FTPClient.cpp -O2 -o FTPClient.obj
g++ -c ./FtpClient/FTPDataTypes.cpp -O2 -o FTPDataTypes.obj
g++ -c ./FtpClient/FTPFileStatus.cpp -O2 -o FTPFileStatus.obj
./FtpClient/FTPFileStatus.cpp:136:2: warning: no newline at end of file
g++ -c ./FtpClient/FTPListParse.cpp -O2 -o FTPListParse.obj
g++ -c MyStringAnsi.cpp -O2 -o MyStringAnsi.obj
In file included from MyStringAnsi.cpp:1:
MyString.h:257:7: warning: no newline at end of file
In file included from MyStringAnsi.cpp:3:
./Macros.h:22:7: warning: no newline at end of file
MyStringAnsi.cpp:1350:2: warning: no newline at end of file
MyStringAnsi.cpp: In member function â€void MyStringAnsi::operator+=(char)â€™:
MyStringAnsi.cpp:1102: warning: NULL used in arithmetic
g++ -lstdc++ -c  MainProgram.cpp `mysql_config -–libs` -O2 -o MainProgram.obj `mysql_config –-cflags`       
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

g++ -lm -lstdc++  -Wall -O2   BlockingSocket.obj FTPClient.obj FTPDataTypes.obj FTPFileStatus.obj FTPListParse.obj MyStringAnsi.obj MainProgram.obj -o my_program
g++: MainProgram.obj: No such file or directory
make: *** [MainProgram] Error 1
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some newlines in the makefile in your question. Also, please provide the _complete_ output when building from scratch.

Comment: Added complete output when building from scratch.

Comment: To start with, when compiling to an object file you don't need libraries and there's no linking being done. Also you should try the failed command yourself in a shell, and also check what the `mysql_config` commands actually returns.

Comment: mysql_config --libs returns: -rdynamic -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto; mysql_config --cflags returns: -I/usr/include/mysql  -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. I solved the problem.
First, as Joachim suggested in comment, I removed librarries from build to object
Second, instead of using mysql_config --libs, I put the path manually

Now makefile is edited as belows:

```
CFLAGS = -lm -lstdc++  -Wall -O2 -L/usr/lib/mysql/ -lmysqlclient

$(CC) -c  MainProgram.cpp -O2 -o MainProgram.obj -I/usr/include/mysql/
```